# SET variable for use as field in query?

Tags: mysql

I feel like I've done this before but missing something. I'm going through a database I inherited and want to see a bunch of DISTINCT values. I was thinking I could do something like this instead of writing cf_840 (or whatever number) a bunch of times and just change the actual field name in one spot...

```
SET @var = 'cf_840';
SELECT DISTINCT @var, COUNT(@var) AS counter 
FROM vtiger_leadscf 
GROUP BY @var 
ORDER BY @var;
```

But this isn't working right and I feel like I'm missing something simple but can't find the right thing to search on SO.

Comment: Dynamic SQL only. Also DISTINCT should be omitted.

Comment: Actually, DISTINCT should be moved to inside the COUNT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use variables to directly specify fields outside of dynamically constructing a query; at best you can choose a value from a field conditionally, like `CASE @var WHEN 840 THEN cf_840 WHEN 1 THEN cf_1 .... etc END AS fieldVal`

Otherwise, you need to dynamically construct a query string with the field name "baked" into the query that gets executed.

C# style: `var query = String.Format("SELECT {0}, COUNT(DISTINCT {0}) AS counter FROM .... blah blah blah", fieldName);`

SQL Proc Style: `SET query := 'SELECT ' + fieldName + ', COUNT(DISTINCT ' + fieldName.....and so on`, then PREPARE and EXECUTE.

---

<s>Edit: I'm not sure why you're selecting @var if you're getting the count of its values. I am guessing you want the field name included in the result, so perhaps the examples would be better as `SELECT '{0}' as theField, COUNT(DISTINCT {0}) AS counter ...` and 'SELECT ''' + fieldName + ''' AS fieldName, COUNT(DISTINCT ' + fieldName ....`</s>

*Also, you should not need GROUP BY or ORDER BY clauses, these queries will have only one result row.*

Comment: Thanks, accepted this answer.  Overally trying to see what data we have in certain columns so we can change UI types w/o anything important getting lost.  They do return more than one result so GROUP BY is needed to differentiate between blanks, 0s, and 1s for example in something ilke "SELECT cf_840, COUNT(cf_840) FROM vtiger_leadscf GROUP BY cf_840" so I can see the count of each different value in the column.

Answer (score -1):

To use a variable in the current query, declare it in the body of the SELECT

```
SELECT DISTINCT @var := 'cf_840' AS fieldName, COUNT(@var) AS counter 
FROM vtiger_leadscf
GROUP BY fieldName 
ORDER BY counter;
```

Comment: This is just going to give a result with the specified string and the number of rows in the table.

Comment: updated my answer. It works right. Get the number of records grouped by field.

Comment: Nope, that is always going to result in a single row with the string "cf_840" and the number of rows in the table. It is equivalent to `SELECT 'cf_840' AS fieldName, COUNT('cf_840') AS counter FROM vtiger_leadscf GROUP BY fieldName ORDER BY counter;`